# I cannot add source to this chart, nor can I remove legend title

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, plotly, legend

I have created a simple interactive chart, of Brazil bank NPLs (no longer interactive as saved as a png) using the below code, but need to refine the aesthetics a bit more to exclude the legend title (series.name) and also the source (caption) does not show at the bottom of the chart. I am relatively new to R, but I suspect the reason is that I am using the ggplot2 and plotly packages in combination? These functions work in my other charts which are all static. I would really appreciate some guidance here.

```
library(GetBCBData)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
id.series <- c(Total_NPL = 21082,
             Corps_NPL = 21083,
             Indivs_NPL = 21084)
first.date = '2011-09-01'
# get series from bcb
 df_cred <- gbcbd_get_series(id = id.series,
                             first.date = first.date,
                             last.date = Sys.Date(),
                             use.memoise = FALSE)
  # check output
   glimpse(df_cred)
 p <- ggplot(df_cred, aes(x =ref.date, y = value, colour = series.name)) +
   geom_line() + 
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("chartreuse3","deepskyblue3", "darkorange2"))+
   labs(y = "% of total loans",
          x = '')+
   labs(y = "% of total loans",
                   x = '',
                   title = "NPL Ratios Brazil % loans ",
                   caption = "Source: Source: SGS - BCB (by GetBCBData)") +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b %y")+
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "azure1"))+
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey", linetype = "dotted"))+
   theme(legend.position="top") +
   theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
   theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12))+
   theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 18))+
   geom_text(show.legend = FALSE,aes(label = value),
                   data = df_cred %>% filter(ref.date == max(ref.date)),
                   nudge_x = 70,
                   nudge_y = 0.08,
                   size = 4.5)+
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,NA), expand = c(0,0))+
   geom_hline(yintercept=0)
   ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, OP.  You want to remove the legend title and the caption?  By "legend title" is this the words above your legend or the legend key names?  It would be helpful to show by posting a picture of the plot and highlighting what you want it to look like.  Also, `labs(caption = ...")` is affecting your caption title.  Legend title is going to match the column name in your data, but can be overwritten.  In this case, you can set `color = NA` or `color = NULL` in `labs()` to remove the title.

Comment: I want to remove the legend title and add a caption....sorry, my chart did not load it is too big I think. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Then the fix is `labs(... color = NULL, caption = "your text for caption"...`.  Right now, you would need to add the entry in `labs(...` for `color=` and change the existing entry for `caption = `.

Comment: file:///private/var/folders/7b/n4p9tspd44v2dhylztvhtv2r0000gn/T/RtmpLALSzN/viewer-rpubs-60d211ab657.html

Comment: Hopefully you can see the chart now, there is no source/caption and I am trying to remove series.name from above the legend

Comment: http://rpubs.com/VGalliano1/NPL_Iactive_Dec21

Comment: The chart on Rpubs; series.name above the legend is not needed

Comment: Is it really necessary for us to recreate your data programmatically via that package? It's not a common one, and I suspect many will be averse to install arbitrary packages (for a variety of reasons). Since your question is about [tag:ggplot2] and [tag:plotly], and not about getting the data. I suggest you reduce your question by removing that package and that call, instead including actual data using `dput(x)`, where `x` is a representative sample sufficient to show what you need.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ggplot` call I did a few things differently. In `scale_colour_manual`, I added `name = ""`. This removed the legend title.

You called `labs` two times, I commented one set out.
You called `element_blank()` for `layout(legend.title...` but without a name, it wasn't needed. (Removing the name through `scale` removed it from `plotly`, as well.)

After creating the `ggplotly` object, I adjusted the margins so that the legend and caption would be visible. I also grayed out the gridlines. FYI, dotted gridlines are currently not an option in `plotly`. Although, it is a current documented feature request.

One last thing-- you had "source: source:..." In the `ggplotly` call, I removed one of the "source:".

Your slightly modified `ggplot` call:

```
p <- ggplot(df_cred, aes(x =ref.date, y = value, colour = series.name)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("chartreuse3","deepskyblue3", "darkorange2"),
                      name = "") +
  # labs(y = "% of total loans",
  #      x = '')+
  labs(y = "% of total loans",
       x = '',
       title = "NPL Ratios Brazil % loans ",
       caption = "Source: Source: SGS - BCB (by GetBCBData)") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b %y") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "azure1"))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey", linetype = "dotted"))+
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  # theme(legend.title = element_blank())+  # this is not doing anything
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 18))+
  geom_text(show.legend = FALSE,aes(label = value),
            data = df_cred %>% filter(ref.date == max(ref.date)),
            nudge_x = 70,
            nudge_y = 0.08,
            size = 4.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,NA), expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)
```

Updates post `ggplotly`:

```
ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(
    margin = list(b = 50, t = 75),  # make space to see the legend/caption
    legend = list(                  # legend placement
      orientation = "h",
      y = 1.06, x = .5, xanchor = "center",
      font = list(size = 12)),
    annotations = list(             # caption and placement
      align = "right", showarrow = F, y = -.08, x = 1,
      # x and y values uses the domain [0,1]
      font = list(size = 10), 
      text = "Source: SGS - BCB (by GetBCBData)",
      xref = "paper", yref = "paper"),        # allow off the plot
    xaxis = list(gridcolor = "lightgrey"),    # gridlines
    yaxis = list(gridcolor = "lightgrey")     # gridlines
  )
```

`ggplot` and `ggplotly`

[image: ggplot] [image: plotly]

Comment: Kat thank you so much for this! I really do appreciate you taking the time to explain my code errors and inconsistencies, as well as the aesthetic limitations within ggplotly. My chart now looks great.